# pandas series looking up the dictionary and updating count

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary that keeps the record of the occurrence of tuples.

```
permute_lst=[('NN', 'shoe'), ('JJ', 'new'), ('NN', 'shirt'), ('JJ', 'vintage')]
```

An example from the pandas series is like this.

```
df['term'][0] = [('NN', 'shoe'), ('NN', 'jacket'), ('NN', 'sock'), ('NN', 'coat'), ('JJ', 'glittering')]
```

My current code is shown below.

```
permutation_mapping = defaultdict(int) 
for p in permute_lst:
    k, v = p, 0
    for i in range(len(df['term'])): 
        for tup in df['term'][i]:
             if tup in permutation_mapping:
                permutation_mapping[k] = permutation_mapping.get(k, 0)+1
```

The result I got is an empty dictionary
 `defaultdict(int, {})`

What I expect is domething like this: `{'('NN', 'shoe')': 1, '('JJ', 'new')': 0, '('NN', 'shirt')': 0, '('JJ', 'vintage')': 0}`

Comment: the whole point of a defaultdict is that you don't have to do `permutation_mapping[k] = permutation_mapping.get(k, 0)+1`

Comment: That is to say, I can just use `permutation_mapping[k] +=1` right? I thought using the `get` function is more computationally efficient, so I used the `get` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas` , you can using `tolist` re construct your dataframe , then using `isin` with `value_counts`

```
ndf=pd.DataFrame(df.term.tolist())
ndf[ndf.isin(permute_lst)].stack().value_counts()
Out[223]: 
(NN, shoe)    2
dtype: int64
# if need dict adding to_dict
ndf[ndf.isin(permute_lst)].stack().value_counts().to_dict()
Out[224]: {('NN', 'shoe'): 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which worked well. I also would love to know what's wrong with my current code? Any suggestion?